# How to detect collision between a list of Rect and another list of Rects

Tags: python, pygame

So I am making a zombie shooter game in pygame. I have a player - a zombie list - and a bullets list.
all of them are rectangles.

I need to detect the collision between all the bullets and all zombies. - i tried `colliderect` but and `collidelist` but that is between a object and a list. I want a list and another list.

when i try doing:

```
def collide(self):
    for zombie in self.zombies:
        index = self.zombie.collidelist(self.bullets)
        if index:
            print("hit")
```

in zombie class it gives error TypeError: Argument must be a sequence of rectstyle objects.

https://github.com/tejasnarula/zombie-shooter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function that can directly test for collisions between 2 lists of rectangles in pygame, unless you are using [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). If you have 2 [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) objects (`group1` and `group2`) you can do the following:

```py
if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(group1, group2, True, True):
    print("hit")
```

If you have to lists of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelistall) objects (`rect_list1` and `rect_list2`) you can use [`collidelist()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) or [`collidelistall()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelistall) in a loop. e.g.:

```py
for rect1 in rect_list1:
    index = rect1.collidelist(rect_list2)
    if index >= 0:
        print("hit")
```

```py
for rect1 in rect_list1:
    collide_list = rect1.collidelistall(rect_list2)
    if collide_list:
        print("hit")
```

If you don't have [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelistall) objects, you need to create them and run the collision test in nested loops:

```py
for zombie in self.zombies:
    zombieRect = pygame.Rect(zombie.x, zombie.y, zombie.width, zombie.height)
    for bullet in self.bullets:
        bulletRect = pygame.Rect(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.width, bullet.height)
        if zombieRect.colliderect(bulletRect):
            print("hit")
```